# How to convert \303\255 to "í" in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, python-2.x, google-speech-api

I'm using Google Speech API and since i'm using LongRunning functions for wav files, and they're all in pt-BR language, they're returning with content such as "voc\303\252 hoje boa noite cart\303\243o".

How can I convert this back to UTF-8?

I already tried .encode function, and already tried to check if there's any parameter to send, but I cannot find anything.

```
    # [START def_transcribe_gcs]
    def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
        """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
        from google.cloud import speech
        from google.cloud.speech import enums
        from google.cloud.speech import types
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=8000,
        language_code='pt-BR')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=300)

    # Print the first alternative of all the consecutive results.
    for result in response.results:
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))

    ##This part is mine, the rest of the code belongs to Google
    file = open("Test.txt", "wb")
    file.write(str(response.results))
    file.close()
# [END def_transcribe_gcs]
```

Comment: How are you examining this data? It sounds like it may already be UTF-8, and you're just misunderstanding the presentation of whatever you're using to read the data.

Comment: Should that example string print as `você hoje boa noite cartão` ?

Comment: This is what's being provided when I do a http request, if I print response.result, or if I do write the content of response.result in a file, it's being recorded as \303\251 (each special character is converted, this one is just an example)

I'm recording the response.result as:

file.write(str(response.result))